# AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to [Amazon S3 documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-server-side-encryption-with-customer-provided-keys/) I'm trying to download file content from Amazon S3 on Android device using the S3 latest sdk.

```
final AmazonS3Client mAmazonS3Client = getS3Client(getAwsDataAccessKey(), getAwsDataSecretKey(), getAwsDataRegion());

// set decryption key
final SSECustomerKey sseCustomerKey = new SSECustomerKey(getPolicySseCustomerKey());

// create request
final GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(getAwsDataBucketName(),getPolicyKey())
        .withSSECustomerKey(sseCustomerKey);

// download
final S3Object s3Object = mAmazonS3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
// get content
objectContent = s3Object.getObjectContent();
```

Then I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: ...), S3 Extended Request ID: ..
```

All the credentials are correct. 
Also in the same way I can read not encrypted file.
**What can it be?**

Comment: Can you confirm the permissions on the object on the AWS S3 console are correct?

Comment: yes, I can download that with Python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to encode `getPolicySseCustomerKey()` to `base64`